# explode string using two delimiters and loop through result

Tags: php, explode, mpdf

After two days of searching through this website, i can't find a proper way to solve my request, so please guide me.

I have a string that might contain several pair of delimiters inserted in different positions in string, ex:

The quick [begin]brown fox[end] jumps over [begin]the lazy[end] dog.

or

[begin]The quick brown[end] fox jumps over the [begin]lazy[end] dog.

What i need: every time i find those delimiters i want to display delimited content in two columns in pdf, but also keeping the rest of the string before and after those delimiters.

Asuming the first example from above I need to get the following result:

```
The quick
$mpdf->SetColumns(2); 
brown fox
$mpdf->SetColumns(0);
jumps over 
$mpdf->SetColumns(2);
the lazy
$mpdf->SetColumns(0);
dog
```

This is the function I'm using from php.net, but as you can see it only works for a single pair of delimiter, i don't know how to use foreach here and also keep the format i need:

```
    function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$exploded = multiexplode(array('[begin]','[end]'),$mystring);

//if delimiters exist, then split in two columns only those parts of the string
if (count($exploded) > 1) {

//begining of the string
$mpdf->WriteHTML($exploded[0]);

//split in two columns
$mpdf->SetColumns(2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($exploded[1]);

//reset to single column and write the rest of the string
$mpdf->SetColumns(0);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($exploded[2]);

} else {
//set two columns for the entire string
$mpdf->SetColumns(2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($mystring);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out `preg_split`. It is similar to explode but you can use regular expression as delimiter.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Here is an example, by using either [begin] or [end] as a delimiter:
https://3v4l.org/nlC9K

The code:

```
$string = 'The quick [begin]brown fox[end] jumps over [begin]the lazy[end] dog.';

$array = preg_split('/\\[begin\\]|\\[end\\]/', $string, -1);

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The quick 
    [1] => brown fox
    [2] =>  jumps over 
    [3] => the lazy
    [4] =>  dog.
)
```

You can remove the excess spaces with [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

**UPDATE:** Code based on your example:

```
$exploded = preg_split('/\\[begin\\]|\\[end\\]/', $mystring, -1);

// Iterate through the array
foreach($exploded as $key => $string) {
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(trim($string));
    if($key++ % 2 == 0) {
        // Every 2nd one
        $mpdf->SetColumns(0);
    } else {
        // Every odd one
        $mpdf->SetColumns(2);
    }
}
```

Again, I'm not sure what the SetColumns are supposed to achieve - maybe you need to handle it differently if there is only one element in the array, maybe you need an additional one to close it after the last one. But this should be a good start.

Comment: Please include the code in the answer itself as external references may become invalid in the future.

Comment: thank you, Andrew, can you tell me please how can i use your example in my request?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, i'm definitely not familiar with mpdf and what setColumns is supposed to do. The key is that you will need to use foreach to iterate through the array. I'll update my answer soon with an example, but I'm not certain it will work the way you'd like.

Comment: @Mircea T I updated my answer. Again, it may not perfectly achieve what you intended, but you can modify it how you see fit.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it. 

To give more information to my question, let's put the question like this: echo the entire string and every time you find a pair of delimiters like [begin]text[end] write "text - OK" then continue with the rest of the string..
in my case, instead of "text-ok" i should add $mpdf->setColumns(2) in order to display the delimited text in 2 columns in pdf

Comment: Well then my example might not be what you're looking for. What it does is that it sets the column for 0-2-0-2-0-2 dynamically, as per the desired result in your original question. Either way, the $key variable in the foreach is the incrementing array key, starting from 0 - you will probably have to write some IF statements based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a way to solve my request. Scrolling down to the same page at php.net i found this function available:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
$ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
array_shift($delimiters);
if($delimiters != NULL) {
    foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
         $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
    }
}
return  $ary;
```

}

Using this function and hints from Andrew (thank you!) my code looks like this now:

```
            $exploded = multiexplode(array('[begin]','[end]'),$mystring);

        //if delimiters exist, then split in two columns only those parts of the string
        if (count($exploded) > 1) {

        //slice the array from begining
        foreach(array_slice($exploded,0) as $key=>$explode) {
            //show the first slice of the array
            if ($key == 0) {
            $mpdf->SetColumns(0);
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($explode[0]);
            //get the rest of sliced array and set it to 2 columns
            }   else if ($key > 0) {
            $mpdf->SetColumns(2);
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($explode[0]);
            //if delimiters [end], then reset columns to 0 and continue with the rest of the sliced array
            $mpdf->SetColumns(0);
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($explode[1]);
            }
        }

        } else {
        //set 2 columns to entire string
        $mpdf->SetColumns(2);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($mystring);
        }
```

I'm sure there are other better options, so please feel free to add your code. Thank you. [image]